# How to match URL with href in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, href

Using a list for navigation, I am looking for a clean way to apply the 'selected' class to a list item if the page URL (minus anything after the path) matches the href of the list item (minus anything after the path).

Example:

```
<li><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
```

Apply class "selected" to the list item when the page URL includes the **/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635** part of the href.

So far, I achieved partial results using:

```
$('.leftNav li a').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href == this.href){
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    }
});

<ul class="leftNav">
<li><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764?ab=leftNav:capris">capris</a></li>
</ul>
```

This, however, **only applied the 'selected' class when the URL matched the href exactly** - meaning it had to include the link-tracking variable as in the href (ie: `?ab=leftNav:dresses`). Thinking of ways to match the "base" URL's and href's, I tried adding a data attribute to the list items to match the path only:

```
$('.leftNav li').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href == (this).data('left-nav-href')){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});

<ul class="leftNav">
<li data-left-nav-href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635"><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
<li data-left-nav-href="/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764"><a href="/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764?ab=leftNav:capris">capris</a></li>
</ul>
```

I attempted this with variations of window.location including: `window.location.href`, `window.location.href.pathname`, `window.location.href.indexOf`, `window.location.href.startsWith`. With this not working, I searched for a way to match the path of the URL and href regardless of additional parameters or variables, but all I can find are ways to match URL's and href's specifically *with* strings or parameters. All instances I could find of matching only part of a URL or href use "split" RegEx which introduces another level of complexity that I don't think my use requires. Am I missing a simpler solution?

Comment: Please explain down-votes to help us improve. Thanks.

Comment: Same here .. someone downvoted my answer I don't know why .. whatever ..@paulmz I update my code with example .. check it

Comment: Both Mohamed-Yousef's and Vinas' answers appear to function correctly. I'm just going to work with them for a day before marking a correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still testing both Mohamed-Yousef's and Vinas' answers. I don't see any negative impacts using either version. Since performance and output appear identical, I'm leaning towards Vinas' answer just because it's one line less code. But if anyone can describe why one version might be more beneficial than the other, I'm open to suggestions before marking a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `indexOf()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.leftNav li a').each(function(){
        var ThisHref = ($(this).attr('href').split('?'))[0];
        if(window.location.href.indexOf(ThisHref) > -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
        }
   });
});
```

**Example**

```js
var url = "http://www.website.com/index/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764?ab=leftNav:capris";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.leftNav li a').each(function(){
        var ThisHref = ($(this).attr('href').split('?'))[0];
        //alert(ThisHref);
        if(url.indexOf(ThisHref) > -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
        }
   });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="leftNav">
<li><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
<li><a href="/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764?ab=leftNav:capris">capris</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // run the code after document is ready
    $('.leftNav li a').each(function(){ // loop through <a> on <li>
       // $(this).attr('href') will return href as string .. in your case will return something like '/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses'
       // using .split('?') to separating this href string by '?'
       // [0] get the first string after split (in this case it will be '/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635')
       // combine all of those steps on just one line
       var ThisHref = ($(this).attr('href').split('?'))[0];
       // get the 'window.location.href' which is return your url ..something like 'http://www.website.com/index/p/clothing/bottoms/capris/N-10764?ab=leftNav:capris'
       // try to find (first string after split) into (url/window.location.href)
       if(window.location.href.indexOf(ThisHref) > -1) { // if the url contains the first string after split addClass
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected'); 
       }
    });
});
```

you can read about [.split() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

> Note: in Vinas answer he use `this.href` which will return href as
>   string .. in your case will return something like
>   '/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses' and he use
>   [location.pathname](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)
>   and the code of `indexOf()` he try to find the `location.pathname`
>   into the `href`

**Additional**: *in your case* both my answer and Vinas answer will work . that's not depending on code its depending on your case and what you're trying to do .. something like `.hide(0) , .slideUp(0) , fadeOut(0)` all of those hide the element with same effect .. So the code always determine by the case you working with .. May be my code or even Vinas's code won't work on another case

Comment: I'd do == 0 rather than > -1, but your solution does answer the question

Comment: This seems to only work the same as my first attempt in the OP where it only matches the entire URL. Navigating to **/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses** adds the class to the list item, but navigating to any other variation of the URL, for instance **/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635** which does not have the **?ab=leftNav:dresses**, does not trigger the match.

Comment: Clever approach. I think stripping everything after the '?' from `ThisHref` would make it work.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef the updated example does indeed work, but I thought that .split was a RegEx? Is using RegEx overkill for the small amount of href's that I need to match?

Comment: I also tried "== 0 rather than > -1" like @ControlAltDel suggested and it still works. What's the difference?

Comment: @paulmz to avoidusing  `split()`  you can return to your second attempted by using `data-url` attribute  and then use `var ThisHref = $(this).data('url');` .. about `== 0` sure `0` is bigger than `-1` so it will return true as well

Comment: @paulmz read about [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) **

Comment: @paulmz `.split()` isn't necessarily RegExp and it sure isn't overkill. I don't know why you try avoiding it.

Comment: @Botimoo I honestly don't know why I'm trying to avoid it, either. I've just been reading through dozens of posts and articles for several days and I found more examples of .split and RegEx with comments like "but it uses RegEx" and then they tried to figure alternatives. Led me to believe that using RegEx is not a best practice. Still learning.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you keep your html like

```
<li><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
```

but change the comparisson to:

```
$('.leftNav li a').each(function(){
    if (this.href.indexOf(location.pathname) > -1) {
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

you'll get what you need!

The "if" above will check if the given path is contained in item's href property.

So, if your URL is "http://www.yourhost.com/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?param=value", it's path (/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635) should be found, and the output for the given example would be:

```
<li class="selected"><a href="/p/clothing/dresses/N-10635?ab=leftNav:dresses">dresses</a></li>
```

I hope this helped! =)

Comment: This also seems to work. Although I don't understand the difference, I also tried `$('.leftNav li a').each(function(){
     if (this.href.indexOf(window.location.pathname) > 0) {
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    }
});` and it still worked. Any reason to use one version versus the other (`window.location.pathname` vs `location.pathname` and `>0` vs `>-1`)?

Comment: For "window.location" vs "location" : I guess you're right "window.location" may actually be better, for it cannot be overwritten. A local command like "var location = 1;" would overwrite "location".

Comment: For the second question: indexOf() method returns the index where the string was found. As in any array, it starts counting from 0.

If we have:
    var str = "this is a test";

Then console.log(str.indexOf("test")) would print "10", but console.log(str.indexOf("this")) would print "0".

Only when the string is not found, -1 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there isn't any '?' character in the actual path you could use something like this for both the location and the href:

```
function getBaseURL(url) {
    return url.split('?')[0];
}
```